# How can PHP pull the JSON data from VIMEO API and print it on XML file?

Tags: php, json, xml, api, vimeo

I am calling the following Vimeo API to return all the videos under the specific videos. What I was trying to achieve is to only pull the particular JSON data that I desire to. "uri" and "name" is the only data that i need. And how can I print this thing to a XML file?    https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/folders#get_project_videos

BTW this is my attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <?PHP

      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
      require ("vendor/autoload.php");
      use Vimeo\Vimeo;

      $client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

      $user_id = '121265018';
      $project_id = '2370434';
      $response = $client- 
      >request("/users/$user_id/projects/$project_id/videos");

   var_dump($response);
   if ($response['status'] === 200) {
   $videos = [];
   foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
     $result = [
       //'uri' => $data['uri'],
       'name' => $data['name'],
       //'pictures' => $data['pictures'],
     ];
     $videos[] = $result;
   }

   echo json_encode($videos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
  } else {
    echo json_encode($response['body']['error']);
  }


   ?>
```

[image]

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json')` makes no sense there to begin with. You have already created HTML output at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to save the three things in a separate array and then print at the format that you want.

**UPDATE**

you have an array of data with all your videos. sow you need to use a foreach to get uri, name and pictures of all videos and save in another array.

```
<body>
  <?PHP
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  require("vendor/autoload.php");

  use Vimeo\Vimeo;


  $client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

  $user_id = '121265018';
  $project_id = '2370434';
  $response = $client->request("/users/$user_id/projects/$project_id/videos");
  if ($response['status'] === 200) {
    $videos = [];
    foreach ($response['body']['data'] as $data) {
      $result = [
        'uri' => $data['uri'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'pictures' => $data['pictures'],
      ];
      $videos[] = $result;
    }

    echo json_encode($videos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
  } else {
    echo json_encode($response['body']['error']);
  }
  ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: uri in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\GP.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\GP.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: pictures in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\GP.php on line 29
{"uri":null,"name":null,"pictures":null}

Comment: is it bcoz the URI, Name and Picture is under the array of "Data"?? I've update my question with the actual API JSON data to show u. But

Comment: I tried two ways 1) 'uri' => $response['data']['uri'],   2) 'uri' => $response['body']['data']['uri'], but looks like its not working :(

Comment: you need to know wheres is the keys that you want, give `var_dump($resquest);`  and look for your keys location, and then save then in another array.

Comment: based on the changes on my code above, what u mean is I should user var_dump to output my JSON array? var_dump($response) ??

Comment: you error is that you trying to access a key key in the wrong place, add at first line of your if statement a `var_dump($response);` and then search for your keys correct locations

Comment: the [video api link](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/folders#get_project_videos) that you put in question have an response example and have a lot of `"uri", "name", "pictures"` and i don't know what is the correct ones

Comment: Bro im sorry for the confusion i made, maybe I should put my question in this away. I've updated my question with the latest photo. The one I highlighted in blue, is the only JSON data that I wanted to take from the API. As I uploaded more than one video, and each video has different "URI", "name",  "description", and "pictures".  So I'm trying to get this specific JSON data info from all the videos.

Comment: based on your image, you have a aray data inside your result, sow you need to use foreach to get all videos inside him. i updated the answer with a foreach

Comment: Its partially works now bro, but just wonder why there is a warning message. But the data is printed out fine.    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\GP.php on line 28
[]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220668/discussion-between-andre-walker-and-beyond).

Comment: that's odd. talk to me in chat and and me your code.

Comment: Okay i have uploaded the relevant information in the chatroom

Comment: Hi bro i have one last question in our chatroom. I don't know whether my question is logical and applicable or not. Based on your experience, do you think this is applicable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace line

```
 $jsondata = file_get_contents($response);
```

with

```
 $jsondata = $response['body'];
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$json' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\GP.php on line of $json = json_decode($jsondata,true);

Comment: add ; add end of the new line with $jsondata

Comment: i think its the syntax error. Coz even after I added ; it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '；' (T_STRING) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\GP.php on line 29